# looping one variable and printing from other

Tags: shell, loops, sh

I have a shell script that has two variables, ip and mask.
The variable ip contains ip addresses. I do not know how many beforehand.
The variable mask contains the corresponding network masks.

I want to print out the ip and corresponding mask in the format:
ip mask\n
ip mask
...

How do I do this?
I would like the script to be portable, but bash is also ok.

```
echo "$ip"
echo "$mask"
# This is how I would like the output to look like:
printf "%s "  `echo "$ip" | awk '{print $1}'` `echo "$mask" | awk '{print $1}'`
printf "\n"
printf "%s "  `echo "$ip" | awk '{print $2}'` `echo "$mask" | awk '{print $2}'`
```

That gives the output:

```
10.3.30.54 10.3.36.17 10.3.36.19 213.15.219.104
255.255.255.255 255.255.255.240 255.255.255.240 255.255.255.255
10.3.30.54 255.255.255.255
10.3.36.17 255.255.255.240
```

Thanks!

Comment: `paste <(printf "%s\n" $ip) <(printf "%s\n" $mask)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
awk -vm="$mask" -vip="$ip" 'BEGIN{n=split(m,a); split(ip,b); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print b[i],a[i]}'
```

Comment: This works even though it looks a bit complicated to me. Thanks!

Comment: I believe it should be n=split(vm,a) instead of n=split(m,a), right?

Comment: @Tiago No, `-v` is the option passed to `awk`, `m` is the argument to the option.. So `awk` receives the variable `m="$mask"`..

Answer (score 2):

In bash, you can use arrays to hold the IPs and masks:

```
#! /bin/bash
ip='192.168.0.1 127.0.0.1 192.168.0.100'
mask='255.255.255.0 0.0.15.0 127.127.127.0'

ips=($ip)
masks=($mask)

for (( i=0 ; i<${#ips[@]} ; i++ )) ; do
    echo ${ips[i]} ${masks[i]}
done
```

Comment: This is an elegant answer. The only drawback is that arrays are not portable to other shells.

Answer (score 1):

Note: `bash` specific. Will not work with `/bin/sh`

Using [`paste`](http://man.cx/paste) command & [`process substitution`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution):

```
$ paste <(printf "%s\n" $ip) <(printf "%s\n" $mask) 
10.3.30.54  255.255.255.255
10.3.36.17  255.255.255.240
10.3.36.19  255.255.255.240
213.15.219.104 255.255.255.255
```

Explanation:

1. `paste` command: prints both the files side by side.
2. `printf` With `"%s\n"` as format string will print ips/masks on one line each.
3. Using `process substitution`, these two are treated as if they are from file inputs.

Comment: This looks as a solution but it gives me: syntax error near unexpected token `('
    `paste <(printf "%s\n" $ip) <(printf "%s\n" $mask)'

Comment: Are you using `bash` or `sh` ? process substitution is a bash feature. & I happen to miss the `sh` tag in question.

Comment: Thanks for the note! I use sh.